# Django makemigrations wonkyness

Tags: django, django-models

**Issue:** 
    When I run `python makemigrations myapp --settings=mysettings` it detects a change in one of my models that I didn't make. Namely, it detects a 'id' field added to my model without a default. It therefore wants me to provide a one-off default. When I do this, it fails to migrate giving me generic error messages such as the in() argument must be a string or a number, not (whatever I entered, an integer, a string, a datetime, anything as a one-off). The annoying thing about this is that there isn't ID field added and I am not sure why it is detected this change.

**Django Version:** *1.11*

**Python Version:** *2.7.10*

Does anyone have a solution for this issue? (will add updates and more information as requested.)

**Model:**
This is the model that is receiving the ID being added randomly.

```
class Outage(models.Model):
    event_start = models.DateTimeField()
    event_end = models.DateTimeField()
    affected_products = models.ManyToManyField('products.Product')
    severity = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    summary = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    impacted_guests = models.IntegerField()
```

**Update:**
I performed a *--fake* migration to avoid dealing with this issue right now, however when running tests, the test database is getting the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1067, "Invalid default value for 'id'")
```

It says it requires the id for the many to many to work, however it appears to me that it automatically set that up and created the table storing the relationships, which is why I think this error is happening to begin with. As mentioned, after faking this migration, the actual application has no trouble forming the manytomany relationship even though the id was not explicitly set by me.

The issue is, I can't seem to run any tests because the test database wants some sort of explicit hand-holding to set it up properly. Here is more verbose information on my migrations:

**Original Migrations**

```
operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Outage',
            fields=[
                ('event_start', models.DateTimeField()),
                ('event_end', models.DateTimeField()),
                ('severity', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('affected_products', models.ManyToManyField('products.Product')),
                ('summary', models.TextField()),
                ('description', models.TextField()),
                ('impacted_guests', models.IntegerField()),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

**Second Migration: No Default ID (Faked in Real DB)**

```
operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='outage',
            name='id',
            field=models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID'),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
    ]
```

This migration file yields the following error when running tests.

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1060, "Duplicate column name 'id'")
```

as mentioned earlier, this version of the second migration file yields the original result:

**Second Migration: Default ID (Faked in Real DB)**

```
operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='outage',
            name='id',
            field=models.AutoField(auto_created=True, default=1, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID'),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
    ]
```

And then lastly, running a test without any second migration file at all yields the following:

```
ValueError: "<Outage: Outage object>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

Any ideas given the new information?

Comment: Could you post your models? Also did you try to make your database tables differently or tried any manual migrations with your sql engine? This mostly happens when something is added from outside (not using django orm)

Comment: This is a tough question because It is hard to reproduce the problem without divination powers. I bet you will get better answers if you update the question with a minimal application that allows someone to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MohitC I am not doing any manual migrations with the sql engine. I am interacting with the MySQL db instance entirely through django.

Comment: @PauloScardine I am going to make an SSCCE in gist and link it here for you.

Comment: I have gone to only the first issue. I will make a new thread for the second issue later. No point having two issues on one thread.